# What is the fastest way of combining elements of lists in rules?

Tags: list-manipulation

Let us take the following two toy lists:

`{{a,b},{c,d}}` and `{{e,f},{g,h}}`

And let's say that I want to combine them such that I get the following:

`{{a -> e, b -> f}, {a -> g, b -> h}, {c -> e, d -> f}, {c -> g,  d -> h}}`

This can obviously be done with Table, MapThread and who knows how many ways. The question is, what is the fastest way in terms of computational time?

**EDIT**

The lists need not to be of the same dimensions. Fore example, one could have:

`{a,b}` and `{{c,d},{e,f}}`

to get `{{a -> c, b -> d}, {a -> e, b -> f}}`.

Only the last levels of the lists need to have the same number of elements in order to combine them into Rules.

Comment: I'll test the answers on my actual dataset and get back to you to see what is the response of `AbsoluteTiming` for each of your solutions. Best performance gets accepted answer, obivously. Stay tuned :D

Comment: Turns out the fastest one is using `AssociationThread`, at least in my code (which has way longer lists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One straightforward way is with [`AssociationThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationThread.html).

```
keys = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
values = {{e, f}, {g, h}}

AssociationThread @@@ Tuples[{keys, values}]

(* {<|a -> e, b -> f|>, <|a -> g, b -> h|>, 
    <|c -> e, d -> f|>, <|c -> g, d -> h|>} *)
```

And for the second example:

```
keys = {{a, b}}
values = {{e, f}, {g, h}}

AssociationThread @@@ Tuples[{keys, values}]

(* {<|a -> d|>, <|a -> f|>, <|b -> d|>, <|b -> f|>} *)
```

Of course, you end up with a list of `Association`s, but is that such a bad thing? You can always turn it into a list with `Normal`.

As for the second example, it clearly doesn't meet your "lists need not be of the same dimensions" specification. You can either take the one liner and use it on `keys = {{a, b}}` instead of `{a, b}`, or you can use this longer function, but get the functionality you're after:

```
listtorules[list1_, values_] := 
 Block[{keys = If[Depth[list1] == 2, {list1}, list1]},
  Normal[AssociationThread @@@ Tuples[{keys, values}]]
  ]
```

Then

```
listtorules[{a, b}, {{c, d}, {e, f}}]

listtorules[{{a, b}}, {{c, d}, {e, f}}]
```

both produce

```
{{a -> c, b -> d}, {a -> e, b -> f}}
```

Comment: If you use the rules only for `Replace` and friends then `Normal` is actually contraproductive: `Association`s tend to be even more efficient in replacements than hash tables generated with  `Dispatch`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  At least in the examples the set of rules have length 2, and for so short replacement rules `Dispatch` and `Association` usually makes things slower

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher and @Coolwater I have a mild preference for `Association`s over `Rules`, just because it's often cleaner and _can_ be faster, depending on what you're using them for. I personally wouldn't `Normal`ize the `Association`, but I wanted to leave both possibilities open for the OP.

Comment: @Coolwater Good point. I tend to project everything I see to larger list... However, the OP's question was also about performance.

Comment: @aardvark2012 That was not meant as criticism. I stumbled upon this fact quite unexpectedly (note that `Dispatch` is actually _made_ for `Replace`) some time ago. I just thought this could also to be of interest to the OP.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Absolutely. I've never used `Dispatch`, but (as of your comment) I tried a variant of the timing test from the `Dispatch` docs page, and `Association` does indeed come out faster. Also, `Association`s are (marginally) quicker to set up.

Comment: `Dispatch` speeds up everything when there's a large list of rules to apply at the same time, as far as I understand. Here I have a long list of small lists of rules and `Association` seems to perform better.

Answer (score 6):

```
L1 = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
L2 = {{e, f}, {g, h}};

L1r = ArrayReshape[L1, {Times @@ Most[#], Last[#]}] &[Dimensions[L1]];
L2r = ArrayReshape[L2, {Times @@ Most[#], Last[#]}] &[Dimensions[L2]];

new = Transpose[Tuples[{L1r, L2r}], {1, 3, 2}];
new[[All, All, 0]] = Rule;

new
```

> ```
> {{a -> e, b -> f}, {a -> g, b -> h}, {c -> e, d -> f}, {c -> g, d -> h}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Outer`:

```
lst01 = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
lst02 = {{e, f}, {g, h}}
Outer[Thread@*Rule, lst01, lst02, 1]
```

You'll have to use `{{a,b}}` instead of `{a,b}` for your second case.  And if you really need not have a matrix of results, you can `Catenate` the results of the above (but of course that has a cost).